# .Net C# POSTing from a Test project method to a controller method with "Authorize" rule not working

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, testing, post

I'm running a test where I have to do a post request to a controller method in the web (that is already running).

I was able to do posts to other methods (like login), but the problem is that this "RunModel" method requires authentication.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Alto, Medio")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RunModel(Guid id, [FromQuery] int year, [FromQuery] int month)
{
```

I first tried with Postman, for that I created two different requests, one post for "Login" and the second for this method I need to post. I have set breakpoints in both methods and both were hit correctly, so my problem arises when trying to do the post request from my test method.

In Postman if I do:

[image: Login]

and after that:

[image: Post request]

it works correctly, both breakpoints are hit.

But with my Test method:

```
[Fact]
public async void TestModel()
{
    #region Login

    var baseUrl = "https://localhost:xxx";

    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> paramt = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName","xxx"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password","xxx")
        };
    HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(paramt);

    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> paramt2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id","aaa"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("anyo", "2023"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mes","6")
        };
    HttpContent q2 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(paramt2);

    using (HttpClient client = this.context._httpClient)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response1 = client.PostAsJsonAsync(baseUrl + "/Login/Acceder", q).Result;
        var response2 = client.PostAsJsonAsync(baseUrl + "/Pools/Management/RunModel", q2).Result;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The login works just fine (the breakpoint is hit) and after that the second post fails due to authentication problems.

What can I try next?

### Edit 1

I finally realized that I am doing something wrong, the login + the request are two independent request.

I'm trying with basic authentication, but the results are the same:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string username = "xxx";
    string password = "xxx";
    string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
                                   .GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

    var response1 = client.PostAsJsonAsync(baseUrl + "/Pools/Management/RunModel", q2).Result;
}
```

### Edit 2

Another similar attempt (to no avail, though)

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("xxx:xxx");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
var response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl + "/Pools/Management/RunModel", q2);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```